# Get html page with cURL and php after execute angular code

Tags: php, angularjs, curl

I have a cURL which takes an html page from an specified url. But that page contains some angular js directives which write some info on that page.

My question: how to get html page after load angular data ?

In PHP, I did:

```
$ch = curl_init("url here");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Angular directives to issue an XHR request to load resources asynchronously? Could you provide the directives? In general, if it is a resource loaded asynchronously (perhaps HTML) you would need a JS engine to load it (like phantomjs).

Comment: Well, I don't have access to directives. I want to get data from GOG.com website

Comment: It does not change much - something will still have to run javascript for it to be rendered and the final, fully loaded page to be displayed. You could call phantomjs from your PHP code and then process the result inside the PHP code.

Comment: as @MindaugasBernatavičius said you need a javascript engine to execute js code ( Angular ) , you can use V8js in php ! 
"v8js is a PHP extension able to run JavaScript code inside V8, Google's JavaScript interpreter that powers for example Chrome and NodeJS." read more here : https://dzone.com/articles/running-javascript-inside-php